# Usefulness of decomposition of time series in a panel data regression analysis setting?

Tags: regression, time-series, panel-data, cross-section, engineering-statistics

So, I am working with panel data. The different panels are for the different inverters that are present inside a solar plant. Each panel has variables that are time variant and are sampled at a 15 min frequency. Alongside them I have some time invariant variables such as ambient temperature as well. My target variable is the total power generated, which is also a time varying variable.

I am looking to build a regression model on top of this dataset. So, I wanted to know if I should decompose my time series (time variant variables) and remove the trend and seasonal components and then include the decomposed time series in my model? Or can I just ignore the time series component and create a model on top of it as is?

**Edit 1:** *Adding in more details*

So, a solar plant has devices known as inverters. These inverters are responsible for converting the DC power to AC power that is then used. There are in total of 44 inverters across 2 plants. Length of each individual time series is variable, ranging from 2355 timestamps to 3259 timestamps for some inverters. There are in total 5 time variant variables (DC Power, AC Power, Daily Yield, Total Yield, Per Timestamp Yield). There are in total 3 time invariant variables (Irradiation, Ambient Temperature, Module Temperature).

Comment: You need to give more details, mayde explaining what is *different inverters that are present inside a solar plant*, how many of them, length of each individual series, how many time invariant variables, and maybe show us some plots!

Comment: Hi, 
So, a solar plant has devices known as inverters. These inverters are responsible for converting the DC power to AC power that is then used.

There are in total of 44 inverters across 2 plants. Length of each individual time series is variable, ranging from 2355 timestamps to 3259 timestamps for some inverters.

There are in total 5 time variant variables (DC Power, AC Power, Daily Yield, Total Yield, Per Timestamp Yield). There are in total 3 time invariant variables (Irradiation, Ambient Temperature, Module Temperature).

Comment: Can you please add this new information to the post as an edit. Not everybody reads comments!

Comment: I have done it now